# go-swagger injects digits into properties names

Tags: openapi, go-swagger

The models.yaml file I have is:

```
baseStorePatch:
    title: Store
    type: object
    required:
      - scalePolicy
    properties:
      scalePolicy:
          $ref: "#/definitions/scalePolicy"
StorePatch:
    allOf:
      - $ref: "#/definitions/baseStorePatch"
      - type: object
        properties:
```

However, when I use go-swagger to generate the clients, the output is:

```
type StorePatch struct {
    ScalePolicy *StorePatchAO0ScalePolicy `json:"scalePolicy,omitempty"`
}
```

Why the go-swagger auto generate `StorePatchAO0` as the prefix? And how to get rid of it?